# Os diferentes significados de propina

Tags: significado, ortografia, português-europeu

No Brasil **propina** é sinônimo de suborno.

> Como descrito no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/propina): quantia em dinheiro que se oferece a alguém em troca de favor ou benefício quase sempre ilícito: Naquela repartição pública, o serviço só funcionava à base de propina.

Pelo [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/propina), em Portugal, essa palavra é empregada para se referir à taxa de matrícula de escolas.

> Quantia que se paga ao Estado para fazer uma matrícula, um exame, obter a equivalência de diplomas e outros atos.

Como é o sentido de **propina** em Portugal? Nunca está associada a atos ilícitos?

Comment: Pela minha experiência de vida diria que não. Aqui, se falas em propinas as pessoas sabem logo que estás a falar da taxa que pagas para estudar.

Comment: No Brasil (ainda?) se usa propina como sinônimo de gorjeta... porém como as gorjetas raramente chegam às manchetes de jornal, penso que tal uso está destinado ao arcaísmo a curto prazo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, em Portugal `propina` nunca está associado a atos ilícitos.

Em Portugal, as propinas são apenas (3) a taxa que se paga para frequentar a universidade.
Todos os outros significados dados [no Priberam](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/propina) me são desconhecidos:

> 1. Gorjeta, gratificação.
> 2. Quantia que se paga ao Estado para fazer uma matrícula, um exame, obter a equivalência de diplomas e outros actos.
> 3. Quantia paga para frequentar um estabelecimento de ensino superior.
> 4. [Pouco usado]  Jóia que em algumas associações paga aquele que delas quer fazer parte.
> 5. [Brasil, Informal]  Dinheiro ou bem que se oferece a alguém em troca de favor ou negócio lucrativo, geralmente ilícito. = SUBORNO
>
> "propina", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013,  [consultado em 01-07-2016].

Descobrir que no Brasil a palavra `propina` significa [luvas](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/luvas)/suborno, foi uma surpresa tão grande como quando descobri que uma camisola é uma camisa de noite e não uma sweater.

Comment: pt-BR suéter ; luvas não é propina em pt-BR "Santos pagou R$ 400 mil de luvas em renovação do quarto goleiro", está mais para gratificação ou adiantamento.